# Notation question: Subroup generated by two elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

Let there be $H$ subgroup of symmetric group $S_4$, so that $H= \langle (12)(34),(234) \rangle$. What does the notation $\langle (12)(34),(234) \rangle$ mean? I know that if there's one elements, then it's all the powers of that element.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the smallest subgroup that contains both $(12)(34)$ and $(234)$.

This object is well defined as the intersection of all subgroups that contains $(12)(34)$ and $(234)$ because intersection of subgroups is a subgroup.

Another description:

$$
H= \{
a_1a_2\cdots a_n: n\in\Bbb N, \forall k\ \ a_k\in\{ (12)(34),(234)  \}
\}
$$

Comment: So it has nothing to do with powers of said elements?

Comment: see 'another description'.

Comment: Thank you! Is it true to say that since it contains both (12)(34) and (234), then its order is either 6 or 12?

Comment: why is that? what is your argument?

Comment: Sorry, I thought for a second they are disjoint...